How to get the size of files or compressed files inside a compressed file in Linux?
So, essentially I have a compressed file bootcd.tar.gz and it contains a bunch of directories, files and compressed files like (*.tar.gz, initrd.img etc).
How do I calculate the total recursively uncompressed size of bootcd.tar.gz, or how do I calculate the size of one particular file like initrd.img in its decompressed format without decompressing anything and calculating it on the fly.

If you want to consider compressed formats inside the compressed archive, how will you handle for eg. JPEG files? Will you calculate the size of the resulting image?

Ah good question! I only wanted a way to calculate the uncompressed sizes of archives, not really file compression like JPEG, in those cases it's not possible to get the original RAW image, right?

I know the decompressed information can be fetched in only two ways:

With tools like tar, zcat and gzip essentially calculating it on the fly (essentially piping the output), essentially not storing them in disk. Example,

tar -xOf bootcd.tar.gz | wc -c
zcat bootcd.tar.gz | wc -c
gzip -dc | wc -c


Or by reading the metadata of the compressed file using the -l or --list argument with zcat or `gzip.

zcat -l bootcd.tar.gz
gzip -l bootcd.tar.gz

Both the approaches will get me the size of bootcd.tar.gz when uncompressed, but what if it has more compressed files inside it. Lets say for example initrd.img.
To do that we can extract the file initrd.img on the fly using tar and then decompress using zcat by streaming the data from stdin and finally calculate the bytes wc -c
tar -xOf bootcd.tar.gz initrd.img | zcat - | wc -c

Do let me know if you guys have a more elegant solution than this, Thank You!

Does tar -xOf bootcd.tar.gz initrd.img | zcat - | wc -c really work?

@Fravadona Yep! Tested it out and it works
